# How do we store variables for each user on a shopify app?

Tags: shopify, shopify-app

I'm building a simple app where that shows product recommendations.

I want to make it possible for the client to choose how many products he'd like to display, like from 5 or 20 with a liquid variable called {{NofProducts}}

I'm using the shopify app example, there are two important pages:

1. pages/index.js <- here the client can write inputs
2. theme-app-extension/block.liquid <- here we write a liquid code that will be appended to the page.

**How do I pass the inputs from index.js to the block.liquid?**

Do I have to store it elsewhere in a database for each user?
Do I have to create a file using graphQL inside each theme with the user choices using "createScriptTag"?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, unfortunately every Shopify tutorial is extremely confusing for beginners.

They way you pass the store owner inputs to the app is using a database, I did it using Redis, but you can use MongoDB or maybe even a local file, but that's not ideal.

You should not store the user inputs inside their theme, because each time you access or modify a file in the customer's store, you need to use their `getSessionToken` function and make a new request using the token, while using your database you just need to get the session ID using `SESSION_STORAGE`.